# Convert kilobytes to bytes in PHP

Tags: php

How can I convert kilobytes to bytes in PHP? Let's say I get the value 22.2 kb and I want to return this in bytes.

Comment: kb is kilobits. kilobytes is kB.

Comment: @liori: Actually `kb` is an Intel kilobyte: http://xkcd.com/394/

Comment: k = 1,000 and K = 1,024.
b = bits and B = bytes.

So kilobyte = KB.

Ignore what ISO has to say about "kibibytes" and so on; no one uses those in the real world.

Comment: I suppose you also think m = 1,000,000 and M = 1,048,576?  Lots of people use KiB in the real world, and the people who don't use kB = 1000 B.  K = 1024 is flat out wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

multiply by 1024

Comment: "Multiply by 1000", you mean.

Comment: A kilobyte in decimal format is 1000, but for nearly all software purposes you need the binary format which is 1024. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like homework, but 1Kb = 1024 bytes, so you should be able to determine the equation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ever confused for comparable values, you can always google "1 megabyte in kilobytes" and it will return the comparative value.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+MB+in+kB
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+MiB+in+KiB